# Link of a power series by the Bernoullis for a Riccati equation to zonotopes?

Tags: co.combinatorics, differential-equations, sequences-and-series, convex-polytopes, oeis

On pg. 85 of [The Rise and Development of Theory of Series up to the Early 1820s](http://books.google.com/books?id=vLBJSmA9zgAC&pg=PA76&lpg=PA76&dq=series%20reversion&source=bl&ots=UMjErNM3jW&sig=ZbnPVvt1oPYXvBKq5JebtaGbWuQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiy-qHpy9bRAhXHzVQKHbfTBbg4HhDoAQgcMAE#v=onepage&q=series%20reversion&f=false) by Ferraro is a series soln. of

$$ d^2z/z = -x^2dx^2 $$

related to the reputed first appearance of a Riccati-type eqn., addressed by the Bernoulli brothers,

$$dy = y^2dx+x^2dx $$

where $y=-\frac{dz}{zdx}$, an early appearance of the so-called Cole-Hopf transformation.

The series is

$$z= 1-x^4/(3 \cdot 4)+x^8/(3 \cdot 4 \cdot 7 \cdot 8) - x^{12}/(3 \cdot 4 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 11 \cdot 12) + .... $$

and the denominators are $d_n \rightarrow (1,12,672,88704...)$.

Looking for connections to enumerative combinatorics, I found the first three terms of the series in the 5th row of the square table rep of OEIS [A060638](http://oeis.org/A060638/table), related to the combinatorics of zonotopes.

Does this relationship to the OEIS entry persist, at least empirically, for higher order terms?

(Related: [A214916](http://oeis.org/A214916) and a cross-posting as an [MSE-Q](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120390/link-of-a-power-series-by-the-bernoullis-for-a-riccati-equation-to-zonotopes) with a Bessel fct. rep for z.)

Comment: So the first check is whether $T(8,4)=88704$?

Comment: @PietroMajer, yep.

Comment: @PietroMajer,  clearly, the series satisfies the recursion relation in A214916 since $-z^{''}=x^2z $, for a periodic subset of that entry (express $z$ as an e.g.f. as in the draft for the entry), so we need a continuation of T only for comparison.

Comment: The coefficients of $y$ might also be interesting.

Comment: For more on early Riccati equations, see "The origins of Euler’s early work on continued fractions" by Rosanna Cretney